# php MySQL query update column into database.. But It can't show me the updated column value into page

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm new in PHP and MYSQL . Want to learn More. Today I'm Facing some problem like update the value into database. But I solved it out. My code update each row's specific column name 'status' into database. But it still show me same value in page

```
<div class="widget-body" style="height: 290px;">
    <table class="table ">
        <thead>

            <tr>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Starts</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Update</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>   
            <?php
            include 'sql.php';

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT vacation.id, vacation.start_date, vacation.length, vacation.status, userinfo.* FROM vacation INNER JOIN userinfo ON vacation.user_id = userinfo.user_id ");
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
            }
            while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $id = $db_field['id'];
                $uid = $db_field['user_id'];
                $uname = $db_field['username'];
                $sdate = $db_field['start_date'];
                $len = $db_field['length'];
                $stat = $db_field['status'];
                echo("<tr>");
                echo("<td>$uname</td>");
                echo("<td>$sdate</td>");
                echo("<td>$len</td>");
                echo("<td>$stat</td>");
                ?> <td>

                <form method='post' action = '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' >    
                    <input  type='hidden' name="vacation_id" value='<?php echo $id; ?>'/>
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-mini' name='btn-accept' >Accept</button>
                </form>
                <form method='post' action = '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' >    
                    <input  type='hidden' name="vacation_id" value='<?php echo $id; ?>'/>
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-mini'  name='btn-deny' >Deny</button>
                </form>

            </td><?php
                echo("</tr>");

            } //end while-loop
                ?>

            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['btn-accept'])) {
                    $v_id = $_POST['vacation_id'];
                    $SQL = "UPDATE vacation SET status = 1 WHERE id = $v_id ";
                    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                    if ($result === FALSE) {
                        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
                    }
                }

                if (isset($_POST['btn-deny'])) {
                    $v_id = $_POST['vacation_id'];
                    $SQL = "UPDATE vacation SET status = 0 WHERE id = $v_id ";
                    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                    if ($result === FALSE) {
                        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
                    }
                }
             ?>

        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

I know its very old but I'm learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're doing the update after rendering it... Put the update before the output, and it'll probably work as expected.

Comment: @Raphioly-San If I do that then I have to move it into while loop. Which show me all the rows but when click the 2nd row's column for update . It return a warning message and change the value of 1st row's 'status column'

Comment: I mean before the loop. The update is only done after you have pressed the button, so no harm there.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @MarcB You are right, but that's not the question...

Comment: @Raphioly-San: which is why it's a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: @Raphioly-San If I put It before while it show me the warning message and display nothing. If Put it before the 1st query It remain the same . :(

Comment: Would make sense, because I did that wrong in my example. But putting that before the other sql statement should work...

Comment: @Raphioly-San but why not in my  can you share your sample code?? :( if possible

Answer (score 0):

I mean a little like this:

```
        if (isset($_POST['btn-accept'])) {
            $v_id = $_POST['vacation_id'];
            $SQL = "UPDATE vacation SET status = 1 WHERE id = $v_id ";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
            }
       }

       if (isset($_POST['btn-deny'])) {
            $v_id = $_POST['vacation_id'];
            $SQL = "UPDATE vacation SET status = 0 WHERE id = $v_id ";                   
            $result = mysql_query($SQL)
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
            }
        }

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT vacation.id, vacation.start_date, vacation.length, vacation.status, userinfo.* FROM vacation INNER JOIN userinfo ON vacation.user_id = userinfo.user_id ");
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
        }

        while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Comment: Yes sir I already try it. But no update in page. Just update on database.